# Make an Akka-2 instance send itself a message every n TimeUnits without overflowing the mailbox

Tags: scala, actor, akka

An Akka-2 instance should remain in an infinite loop and check every 10 minutes for data to process.

How do I design the loop so that the instance calls upon itself, checks for work to do and then sleeps for an interval?

Also I see that one cannot query the mailbox-size anymore. How do you make sure that  messages are ignored as long as the working-task ( in this case the dispatch function) is active?

```
case class Dispatch()

// Automatical start? The start function has been removed since Akka 2 ?
val dispatcher = system.actorOf(Props[MailDispatcher])

class MailDispatcher extends Actor {

  private val interval = Config.getLong("mail.check.interval")
  context.setReceiveTimeout(Duration(interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS))

  def receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout => {
      self ! Dispatch          
    }
    case Dispatch => dispatch()
    case e: Exception => Logger.error("unexpected Error: " + e)
  }

  def dispatch() {       
      // trigger mail-dispatch       
  }
}
```

Comment: Considering the question in your comment: Yes, Akka 2 has the start method removed and starts actors on creation. See http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-RC1/scala/actors.html#creating-actors-with-default-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

use: http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-RC2/scala/actors.html#initial-receive-timeout

Then when you get a ReceiveTimeout message, you poll for work, and send the work to your own mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've edited the code above but still wondering if the call to Thread.sleep is needed at all? How is the timeout calculated? Does the call to the dispatch-function block timeout-calculation? If the thread sleeps for a year will the mailbox be overflown or is the timeout-value calculated only while the thread is NOT sleeping? If it is not sleeping the call to sleep is unnecessary, I guess.

Comment: NEVER do Thread.sleep(..) in your Actor. For any reason. Just don't.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. If the job always consumes more time than the timeout, the mailbox will eventually fill up, right? Is there any documentation on how to avoid that?

Comment: If you have 1 single message that takes longer than 10 seconds to process, you're probably doing something in a suboptimal way and should possibly break it up into smaller tasks that can be handled piece by piece.

Comment: @Alex Let's turn it around: Why should you?